# Firebase OCR output is wrong

Tags: android, firebase, ocr

I am using Firebase OCR to get a text from an image. I am storing this text in `elementList`, each word separately. When I see what contains `elementList` (see Logcat), I get a lot of strange strings that have nothing related to the real text.

**Java**

```
    private void readTextFromImage() {
        ArrayList<String> frequencyList = new ArrayList<>();
        elementList = new ArrayList<>();
        final Receipt receipt = new Receipt();
        receipt.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        Bitmap b = getBitmapFromImageView();
        if (b != null) {
            FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(b);
            FirebaseVisionTextDetector detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionTextDetector();

            //the main method that extract the texts from image
            Task<FirebaseVisionText> result = detector.detectInImage(image).addOnSuccessListener(firebaseVisionText -> {
                for (FirebaseVisionText.Block block : firebaseVisionText.getBlocks()) {
                    for (FirebaseVisionText.Line line : block.getLines()) {
                        for (FirebaseVisionText.Element element : line.getElements()) {
                            elementList.add(String.valueOf(element));
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d("ciao1elementList3", String.valueOf(elementList));
                }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
> 04-30 00:03:42.978 27079-27079/com.example.ves.gennaio3
> D/ciao1elementList3:
> [com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@a1bd20f,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@e73329c,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@12044a5,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@c45b07a,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@dcd802b,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@9cedc88,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@d758621,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@86e5a46,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@ea1f407,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@7b93934,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@b83635d,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@625d4d2,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@15fc9a3,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@c4ab4a0,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@297d859,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@c686c1e]
> 04-30 00:03:42.979 27079-27079/com.example.ves.gennaio3
> D/ciao1elementList3:
> [com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@a1bd20f,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@e73329c,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@12044a5,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@c45b07a,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@dcd802b,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@9cedc88,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@d758621,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@86e5a46,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@ea1f407,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@7b93934,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@b83635d,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@625d4d2,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@15fc9a3,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@c4ab4a0,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@297d859,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@c686c1e,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@69b5cff,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@2b67acc,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@6e4a115,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@3ab2c2a]
> 04-30 00:03:42.980 27079-27079/com.example.ves.gennaio3
> D/ciao1elementList3:
> [com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@a1bd20f,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@e73329c,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@12044a5,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@c45b07a,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@dcd802b,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@9cedc88,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@d758621,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@86e5a46,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@ea1f407,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@7b93934,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@b83635d,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@625d4d2,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@15fc9a3,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@c4ab4a0,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@297d859,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@c686c1e,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@69b5cff,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@2b67acc,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@6e4a115,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@3ab2c2a,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@9d2ca1b,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@43677b8,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@3fb3991,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@4a7e0f6,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@649ecf7,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@1b75764,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@308ddcd]
> 04-30 00:03:42.982 27079-27079/com.example.ves.gennaio3
> D/ciao1elementList3:
> [com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@a1bd20f,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@e73329c,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@12044a5,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@c45b07a,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@dcd802b,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@9cedc88,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@d758621,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@86e5a46,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@ea1f407,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@7b93934,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@b83635d,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@625d4d2,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@15fc9a3,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@c4ab4a0,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@297d859,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@c686c1e,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@69b5cff,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@2b67acc,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@6e4a115,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@3ab2c2a,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@9d2ca1b,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@43677b8,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@3fb3991,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@4a7e0f6,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@649ecf7,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@1b75764,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@308ddcd,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@7e91682,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@da66193,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@c4485d0,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@8d289c9,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@21618ce,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@c4b83ef,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@8342efc]
> 04-30 00:03:42.983 27079-27079/com.example.ves.gennaio3
> D/ciao1elementList3:
> [com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@a1bd20f,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@e73329c,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@12044a5,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@c45b07a,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@dcd802b,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@9cedc88,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@d758621,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@86e5a46,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@ea1f407,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@7b93934,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@b83635d,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@625d4d2,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@15fc9a3,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@c4ab4a0,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@297d859,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@c686c1e,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@69b5cff,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@2b67acc,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@6e4a115,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@3ab2c2a,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@9d2ca1b,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@43677b8,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@3fb3991,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@4a7e0f6,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@649ecf7,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@1b75764,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@308ddcd,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@7e91682,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@da66193,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@c4485d0,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@8d289c9,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@21618ce,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@c4b83ef,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@8342efc,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@770f985,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@8fef3da,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@776700b,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@7133ee8,
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText$Element@fcca901]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably rather [element.getText()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/text/FirebaseVisionText.Element.html#getText()) than `String.valueOf(element)`.

> Gets the recognized text as a string.

Comment: Yes it is that :)